# How do I apply XACML rules to every child URI?

Tags: xml, soa, xacml, xacml2

I'm working with XACML policies and I have a rule that includes a resource target similar to the following:

```
    <Resources>
      <Resource>
        <ResourceMatch MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:anyURI-equal">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">/MyDirectory</AttributeValue>
          <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"/>
        </ResourceMatch>
      </Resource>
    </Resources>
```

I want this rule to apply to all subdirectories of `/Mydirectory`.  However, if I were to evaluate a request with the resource `/MyDirectory/MySubdirectory`, I would get a `DECISION_NOT_APPLICABLE (3`) response.

Is there an XQuery function that would allow me to apply a rule to all subdirectories of a single directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:function:anyURI-regexp-match and define the AttributeValue as a regular expression..

```
<Resources>
      <Resource>
        <ResourceMatch MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:function:anyURI-regexp-match">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">^/MyDirectory/</AttributeValue>
          <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"/>
        </ResourceMatch>
      </Resource>
</Resources>
```