# Can i use xpath-like expression in the attributevalue in a xacml plicy

Tags: xacml, xacml3, xacml2

I'd like to declare some policies likes:

```
some one can visit anything under the img path, but img folders are scattered everwhere, so the attributevalue in the xacml policy may seem like this: "/rootpath/**XPATH_PART**/img/*".
```

how to write policy of this kind.

I looked through the "XACML3.0 core spec", "Multiple Profile", they says

```
Each Individual Decision Request SHALL be identical to the original request context with two exceptions: the “multiple:content-selector” attribute SHALL NOT be present and an added “content-selector” attribute value SHALL be an XPath expression that evaluates to a single node in the <Content> element
```

I think this means that in the policy file, i cann't use XPath in the AttributeValue to refer to multiple resources like i said in the first place, right? because the request is resolved to individual request each asking for a resource with a specified attribute id.

Is there something in the specification i missed out or misunderstood? or can anyone suggest a better way to do what i want?

Now i'm wondering if using regular expression in the resource can do that. The corresponding function is 
`urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match`.

P.S.: I'm trying to setup a authorization server for my company, XACML seems a good place to start with. But nobody around me knows about it. I would be appreciated if any one can give me any suggestion about setting up the access control system.

Comment: I'd love to help out. What engine or solution are you using? Oil answer your xpath question in a short while

Comment: I try to base the authorization server on Balana (an open source from WSO2).

Comment: If they don't support regexp give the Axiomatics policy server a go

Comment: They do, the regexp is part of xacml core specification.

Comment: Yes you are right but Balana doesn't cover 100% of the spec I believe.

Comment: maybe, but it's open source :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chatted with some of my colleagues at Axiomatics and the conclusion is that you do not need XPath but rather regular expressions. XACML provides a regular expression function that works on URI data types. It is called anyURIRegexpMatch and it takes in a string (the regular expression) and the XACML attribute to which to apply the regular expression. It returns either true or false.

Your rule target would look as follows in ALFA ([Axiomatics Language for Authorization](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products/authorization-for-applications/developer-tools-and-apis/192-axiomatics-language-for-authorization-alfa.html)):

```
policy matchResources{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule allow{
        target clause anyURIRegexpMatch("^https?://(?:[a-z\\-]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$", resourceId)
        permit
    }
}
```

See also this other example (XACML 2.0): [How do I apply XACML rules to every child URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532237/how-do-i-apply-xacml-rules-to-every-child-uri)